# Proof of the Plancherel theorem in Cohen-Tannoudji

Tags: proof-explanation, fourier-transform

In [Quantum Mechanics by Cohen-Tannoudji](https://books.google.com/books?id=KtHoDwAAQBAJ&newbks=0&hl=en&source=newbks_fb) (volume 2, appendix 1), Cohen-Tannoudji gives a proof of the [Plancherel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem). I'm having trouble understanding this proof. Although this is a physics textbook, the question is mathematical and so I've used this site instead of the physics site. Cohen-Tannoudji defines the Fourier transform and its inverse for a 1D wave function as:

$$
\begin{align}
\overline{\psi}(p) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\, e^{-ipx/\hbar} \psi(x)\\
\psi(x) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp\, e^{ipx/\hbar} \overline{\psi}(p)
\end{align}
$$

The Plancherel theorem states:

$$
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx |\psi(x)|^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp |\overline{\psi}(p)|^2
\end{equation}
$$

Cohen-Tannoudji then gives the following proof ($z^*$ denotes a complex conjugate):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx |\psi(x)|^2 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\, \psi^*(x) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp\, e^{ipx/\hbar} \overline{\psi}(p)\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp\,\overline{\psi}(p) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\, e^{ipx/\hbar} \psi^*(x)\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp\, \overline{\psi}^* (p) \overline{\psi}(p)
\end{align}
$$

The first line of the proof and the equality between the second and third lines are clear to me. However, I don't understand how the first and second lines are equal. My best guess for this is that he is somehow swapping $x$ and $p$. Why is line 2 equal to line 3?

Comment: It seems like he's swapping the order of integration. So basically using Fubini's theorem I guess?